# find the root : $x^8-24x^4+256x^2+144=0$

Tags: polynomials, roots

find the root of $\mathbb{R} $:

$$x^8-24x^4+256x^2+144=0$$

my try:

$$t=x^2\\t^4-24t^2+256t+144=0\\t^4-(8×3)t^2+(8×2^5)t+(8×18)=0$$

now ?!!

thank you very much!

Comment: To find answer for such questions, use www.wolframalpha.com

Comment: It is a good start.  The next thing I would check is Rational Roots test, which says (since your polynomial in $t$ is monic) that any rational root must be an integer that divides $144$.  This is an important theme in algebra, so it's worth checking these in order to better appreciate this test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$x^8-24x^4+144=(x^4-12)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

The equation can be factored as 
$$(x^2-8x+36)(x^2+8x+4)=0$$
So here are the roots:
$$x_1 = -2(2+\sqrt{3})$$
$$x_2 = -2(2-\sqrt{3})$$
$$x_3 = 4-2\sqrt{5}i$$
$$x_4 = 4+2\sqrt{5}i$$

Comment: So how do you arrive at those factors?